# Install lamp-server on EC2 at start-up

Tags: amazon-ec2, bash, lamp

I passed some scripts to EC2 userdata to install at starup. One of those is `sudo tasksel install lamp-server`

When this process runs, it prompts for mysql password,twice, to bypass this, I use

```
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password pass"
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password pass"
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

The script runs fine when I ssh into the instance and manually run it. However when I put this into user-data of an EC2, this error happened `can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address`

So is there any work-around?

Comment: Why not make an AMI with all your packages installed, rather than duplicating the effort every time one starts up?

Comment: No I don't want to use custom AMI

Comment: Why not? Easier, takes 2 min, you can do it in the AWS Console. Having MySQL install as part of the userdata is a little bit crazy.

Comment: It's just a requirement, so something simple as this can't be done using bash?

Comment: Installing an entire LAMP setup isn't really "simple", and that's a fairly bizarre client requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try those two AWS options: OpsWorks (Chef), CloudFormation; or build your own AMI.

Comment: May be Chef is my choice since I don't want a custom AMI...but I don't know Chef

Comment: @Casper Then this is what you should read through (and try yourself): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/gettingstarted_intro.html Been using it in production ever since AWS introduced it.

Comment: It looks complex to me and currently I'm too lazy to read all that, all I need is to just install LAMP stack, can I just simply install chef and use a cookbook (probably be me) to install it?

Comment: `I'm too lazy to read all that` - sounds like you need to hire a good AWS specialist.

Comment: Well I don't need all that just to install a lamp stack on an EC2 at start-up...